# PHP: summation needed inside of a loop

Tags: php, foreach, iteration

The student is back. Thanks for you help an patience ;)

I'm using a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ($value as $val)
{
//coming from database, from a select query:
$points = $row['points'];  

//now I want to update another database table:  
 $sql = "update user set totalpoints=".$points." where userid=".$uid." ";

//but by doing this, table user is updated with the value of $points in the last iterarion 

}
```

What do I have to do to update my table with the summation of $points and not with the value of the last iteration?

Thanks again

Comment: Do you mean iterate over all rows, sum all the points values, and insert a new row with the total?

Comment: SQL has a `SUM()` function that you can use. It will be faster than querying each row in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure but it seems you want:

```
$sum = 0;

foreach ($value as $val) {
    $sum += $row['points'];  
}

$sql = "update user set totalpoints=".$sum." where userid=".$uid;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$points = 0;
while ($row = mysq_fetch_array()) // from where you are getting row
{
//coming from database, from a select query:
$points += $row['points'];  

}


//now I want to update another database table:  
 $sql = "update user set totalpoints=".$points." where userid=".$uid." ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it all in one query

I suppose your original query was something like `SELECT * FROM matches WHERE userid='$uid'` (whatever) so instead do something like `UPDATE user SET totalpoints=(SELECT SUM(points) FROM matches WHERE userid='$uid' GROUP BY userid) WHERE userid='$uid'` (Probably it would not fit your exact problem but I hope you get the idea)